# openapi-generator cuts beginning of enum names in generated class

Tags: java, enums, openapi, openapi-generator

Openapi-generator cuts beginning of enum names starting with "SB_". I don't understand why this happens or how to fix this.

This is a part of my openapi.yaml:

```
...
sb:
  type: string
  enum:
    - SB_150_150
    - SB_300_150
...
```

This is the generated class:

```
  public enum SbEnum {
    ...
    _150_150("SB_150_150")
    _300_150("SB_300_150")
    ...
  }
```

When I delete the first underscore from the first enum name the rest of enum names is generated correctly.

How can I achieve a result like this?

```
  public enum SbEnum {
    ...
    SB_150_150("SB_150_150")
    SB_300_150("SB_300_150")
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue as I was working with openapi-generator at the moment, and I encountered the same issue. What resolved it for me was including extra option in the plugin configuration block in my `pom.xml` as follows

```
<configuration>
        <additionalProperties>removeEnumValuePrefix=false</additionalProperties>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps in your case as well, hopefully you don't need those prefixes actually removed somewhere else.

I am using version 6.4.0 of the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`

Comment: Did not work for me. Seriously, why did they do this. All my enum mapping fail now.